# Regex to return different length sentences

Tags: php, regex

I'm tyring to match different length sentences with digits at the begining.
How can I do this and return matches of different lengths?

eg  "2341' Macbeth",
    "2354' The Hunger Games",
    "1236' Crimson Peak"

```
   preg_match_all("d+\\'\s\w+\s\w+(?(?=w))~", $string, $array);
```

Clearly I'm new to regex and programming in general, any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `\d+`.

**[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK8vR2/1)**

If you want to capture then use capturing groups

```
(\d+)
```

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-4]   `2341`
MATCH 2
1.  [17-21] `2354`
MATCH 3
1.  [43-47] `1236`
```

Btw, if you have a multiline sentence, just add the `^` at the beginning to match only line starting with numbers:

```
^(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK8vR2/2)**

[image]

Comment: Hiya, thank you for your response. Just to confirm I'm trying to get the titles back as well, so far I can return only titles of the same number of words.

Comment: @Devstack you can use then `^(\d+)'\s*(.*)`. Check this [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK8vR2/3)

Comment: @Devstack glad to help. Thanks for the tick

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work

```
/^\d+.*?$/
```

---

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/fY9yA5/1

---

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```
^\d+.*?$

Assert position at the beginning of a line «^»
Match a single character that is a “digit” «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match any single character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line «$»
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm getting preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'g' though unfortunately. I must be messing it up. Cheers anyway.

Comment: Thank you, just a minor adjustment on my part and I was able to get it to work. I will vote you up constantly!!!! As soon as I'm able :)